# Firefox zoom 100% not equal to screen size

Tags: firefox, zooming

My desktop screen resolution is 1080x1920 (the monitor is using portrait orientation). I noticed a website I'm working on is showing up in tablet mode in FireFox (Chrome and IE work fine). The media query for tablet styling is

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { ... }
```

So even with some loss for window borders and scroll bars I should have plenty of width for the full desktop site. I checked `screen.width` and it is returning 864. I noticed this is the width IE and Chrome report when zoomed to 125%, but firefox is zoom is at 100%. Is there some setting I'm missing in FF or do I just have to set my default zoom to 80%?